# Why does scala allow single quotes in strings to be escaped?

Tags: scala, language-design

I was just reading a scala tutorial, and it seems that when writing strings, scala treats `\'` as `'`, but also treats `'` as `'`

```
val a = "\'" // evaluates to '
val b = "'"  // evaluates to '
a == b //true
```

This doesn't seem like a desirable property of the language* - why is it so?

Comment: it's like any other language - metacharacters need to be handled specially. `'"' == "\""` should be true in a lot of languages, even though they "look" completely different. escaping is like gift wrapping - the wrapper is removed when the thing is used, and not considered part of the thing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The VM does not care which syntax the source language uses for its string and character literals.

Comment: @MarcB `'"' == "\""` is false in Scala (and produces a warning about comparing values of different types). Did you mean `"'" == "\'"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By allowing `\'` in `""` and `\"` in `''`, there is only one set of legal escape sequences for both string and character literals. This way the language designers didn't have to define two separate sets, which would have made the language specification and the implementation (slightly) more complicated.

Comment: `"'"` - completely parsable, `'"'` - completely parsable, `'''` - completely parsable (sic!), the only non-parsable is `"""`, so only `"` actualy requires escaping (`'` shouldn't be part of escape sequences at all). I suspect escapable `'` might be just some legacy or "just in case" thing for the reasons you've mentioned.

Comment: Or (which is more probably) they've just included all special characters there.

Comment: Or (which is more more probably) just copy-pasted it from Java-spec in times when parser probably didn't work correctly with `'''` (some old old Scala)