# Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported. (BAD_ARGUMENTS)

Tags: scala, go, clickhouse

I'm using `sys.process._` to create and run process like

```
  val clickhouseClient = Process("clickhouse-client --version").!!
  println(s"************************************************** ${clickhouseClient}")
```

This print statement gives me the **clickhouse-client version**.

But if it do the following:

```
  val clickhouseClient = Process("clickhouse-client -q 'show databases'").!!
  println(s"************************************************** ${clickhouseClient}")
```

This give **ERROR** - `Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported. (BAD_ARGUMENTS)`

***My aim is to query the clickhouse-server*** using current approach. Don't know why its failing

Futhermore, In golang you would do something like:

```
submitCommand := `
                   #!/bin/bash
                   set -euf -o pipefail
                   cat %s | clickhouse-client --host=9000 \
                                              --query="INSERT INTO some_table Format some_format" \
                                              --stacktrace
`
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "bash", "-c", submitCommand)
stdout := &strings.Builder{}
stderr := &strings.Builder{}
cmd.Stdout = stdout
cmd.Stderr = stderr
cmd.Run()
```

Not sure how to do this in scala. Are the any better approach to do these things?

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

So doing the following solved the issue:

```
val commandTemplate = "show databases"
val result = Process("clickhouse-client", Seq(s"--query=$commandTemplate")).!!
println(s"The result: $result")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a scala expert I'm sorry, but it looks like it's just a problem with the command-line arguments. This error is coming from clickhouse-client itself:

Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported.

I can reproduce this particular error if the command-line parameters are not correct. Could also be an issue with the quoting as passed through to the command line.

Comment: May want to try escaping the single quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079501/why-does-scala-allow-single-quotes-in-strings-to-be-escaped

Answer (score 0):

```
clickhouse-client -q show databases
Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported. (BAD_ARGUMENTS)
```

try

```
"clickhouse-client -q \'show databases\'"
```

Comment: Tried `Process("clickhouse-client -q \'show databases\'").!!`. Got error `Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported. (BAD_ARGUMENTS)
`